# Is it necessary to define the backward function for the frozen layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network, function-fitting

I have a function fitting network with 4 hidden layers.

I need to find suitable weights for the **first** and the **third** layers,
while the **second** and the **fourth** layers are some kinds of *normalization* layers and do not need to be learned, so I just froze them by setting their learning rate to zero.

My question is:

Should I define **backward function** for those two frozen layers?

I [saw](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp#L230) in caffe that the pooling layer that does not have any learnable parameter has the backward function.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Gradients will propagate down, so you cannot stop otherwise your earlier layers won't get information from above. Treat all units in the frozen layers as additive gates - propagate the gradient * 1 through it (i.e no change to the gradient, but allow propagation).

Comment: @KeirSimmons Many thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a backward pass, otherwise your learning would stop at this layer (nothing below it will learn). Even for non-learnable layers you need to compute **valid gradients**.

Comment: Thank you very much, but by highlighting "valid gradients" do you mean that I should suppose frozen layers are not actually frozen and write their own backward function or interact with the incoming gradient just based on  Keir's comment?

Comment: I mean that it does not matter that the layer is frozen, as long as it is processing data it provides a gradient. For example if you have a layer that multiplies by 123 (and you no longer change this 123) its backward pass should be also outputing 123 times incoming gradient (since d(123*x)/dx = 123). Keir's comment is invalid. If you "pass through" the gradient it will be invalid operation.